# Traffic flow with corridor doesn't return particular road with HERE Traffic

Tags: here-api

I have a particular short road segment using this request with a small corridor width of 1 meter, but it doesn't return the particular road's traffic flow, instead it returns other road ways.

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&corridor=1.31969,103.93263;1.32234,103.93212;1

Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic is given on a tile-basis, so even when asking for a small area you will still receive the data for the whole tile.
Additionally, HERE does not provide flow data for every road. It's usually only available for stretches of bigger roads.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?